# app script Convert Date from API to date specific

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a return value from API data like that: `2022-01-07T12:03:58.273Z` I want to change this date to `2022-01-07 12:03:58`.
My code to convert not working, this is my code:

```
    const txt = result.getContentText()
    const d = JSON.parse(txt)
    const time = d.status.timestamp;
    Logger.log(time)

    // get timezone
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

  // convert date to another formate
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(time, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd _ HH:mm");
  Logger.log(formattedDate)
```

The result is:

```
Execution log
1:07:42 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:07:43 PM  Info    2022-01-07T12:07:43.172Z
1:07:44 PM  Error   
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
coData  @ Untitled.gs:27
```

[image]

Comment: The error message is clear: `Utilities.formatDate()` does not accept three string arguments -> Check the documentation

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate%28Date,String,String%29

Answer (score 0):

#### Converting Date

```
function myfunk() {
  const time = new Date('2022-01-07T12:03:58.273Z');
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(time, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd _ HH:mm");
  Logger.log(formattedDate)
}

Execution log
10:29:18 AM Notice  Execution started
10:29:18 AM Info    2022-01-07 _ 05:03
10:29:19 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: 43k rep and yet an answer for a "read the manual" question that lacks any research effort. And the "answer" doesn't explain anything...